# Getting radiobutton associated ArrayList value in radiogroup in Recyclerview values

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, radio-button, android-radiogroup

[image]

I have a layout like the image. And  there are number of radio buttons inside the RadioGroup in each item. Each radiobutton corresponds to the a particular id which is saved in a arraylist. I need to get  the selection values of all the radio button and to all the radiogroup on a button click in the activity class inside a on click event of a button. Is there any efficient technique to reach to my goals.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using radiogroup in xml then 
you can handle the click event in xml only

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RadioGroup xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_pirates"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/pirates"
        android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>
    <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_ninjas"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/ninjas"
        android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>
</RadioGroup>
```

and in your actvity(that hosts the layout) handle the onclick as this

```
public void onRadioButtonClicked(View view) {
    // Is the button now checked?
    boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();

    // Check which radio button was clicked
    switch(view.getId()) {
        case R.id.radio_pirates:
            if (checked)
                // Pirates are the best
            break;
        case R.id.radio_ninjas:
            if (checked)
                // Ninjas rule
            break;
    }
}
```

As you can see it is taking the id's which you have mentioned in the layout.
It becomes easy now.

**Warning :**
 1. method's return type should be void .

2. method's name should be same as supplied in xml.
3. And it should have parameter view of class View.

As for efficiency , you are just setting the same ClickListener object. so its efficient.

[Source Android docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/radiobutton)

Comment: Okay, this looks promising. But here when I implemented it the issue is how to get recycleritem position in the activity. Coz the model arraylist do depend on the recycler item too.

Comment: If model of recycler view item contains radio button , then set the click listeners at the time of binding the view in adapter .

Rest it depends on the model which you are using in recycler view